# Column formatting changes not saving

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column, json, formatting

For my document library on sharepoint online modern view, I have a column for Title. I've tried to format it so that the height changes dynamically based on how long the title is and when I save it at first the changes work perfectly, but as soon as I reload the page the changes are reverted. Below is the code I'm using:

```
{ 
"elmType": "span", 
"txtContent": "@currentField", 
"style": { 
"white-space" : "normal", 
"height" : "auto", 
"padding-top" : "8px" 
} 
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the JSON part, and it might be an obvious question, but... did you save the view? I often make changes to my document library- adding columns and such- and then forget to save the view. Refreshing then makes it all go away.

Comment: Ya I've tried saving it and it unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue amongst some numbers not displaying properly and a style that created a hyperlink just opening a blank page.

I fixed it by deleting the column formatting code, saving the column, then pasting it back in and it saved successfully, after which, everything started working again